# How to Modify Existing Rewrite Rules?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I'm attempting to modify existing rewrite rules generated by WordPress in order to override the default rewrite rules generated.

I'm using the filter hook `rewrite_rules_array` to obtain an array of existing rewrite rules.

While sifting through the rewrite rules array, there are rewrite rules containing `$` in the array value.

After replacing a set of array key/value pairs, PHP is interpreting the suffix text of the array value containing `$` as a PHP variable.

**For example:** `&feed=$matches[1]`.

When I'm done with my modifications and dump the array, everywhere with `$matches[1]` just appears blank.

**My question is:** How can I get `&feed=$matches[1]` to output as `&feed=$matches[1]` in my array value instead of outputting like `&feed=`?

Both my array keys and array values of the modified rewrite rules are contained within double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow I feel like a huge newblet. This is incredibly simple. Just escape it with a `\`.

`"&feed=$matches[1]"` should be `"&feed=\$matches[1]"`.

EASY.